# Conversion failed using datetime variable in OpenQuery call

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a linked query and I'm having a hard time injecting a calculated variable into the `OPENQUERY` call.

I've found a number of solutions here on Stack Overflow that seem to point to a data type mismatch, but I can't replicate the error outside of the `OPENQUERY` call, so it's confusing to me.

Here's the query in question:

```
SELECT name
FROM OPENQUERY ( [OLTP\SQL2014],
'USE master; DECLARE @FROMDATE datetime2(7) = dateadd(dd, -10, Sysdatetime());     
DECLARE @ToDate datetime2(7) = sysdatetime();
EXEC (''SELECT name from sys.tables 
  INNER JOIN sys.partitions
       ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.partitions.object_id 
WHERE  sys.tables.create_date BETWEEN '''' + @FromDate + '''' AND '''' + @ToDate + 
  '''' AND sys.tables.name LIKE ''''%EXCEPTION%''''
   AND NOT sys.tables.name LIKE ''''%AUDIT''''
   AND sys.partitions.rows <> 0 '')'
)
```

Do I need to abandon the use of variables inside `OPENQUERY`?

Comment: Why are you using SYSDATETIME when you declare a variable with datetime datatype?

Comment: Habitually going to the more precise measurement (as opposed to GetDate()). Any reason I shouldn't?

Comment: Sure, but then you may want to use a datetime2(7) datatype instead of datetime

Comment: That makes sense to me. Otherwise I'm just pointlessly cutting off those digits. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using ugly string concatenation and `EXEC` use parametrized `EXEC sp_executesql` like:

```
SELECT name
FROM OPENQUERY ( [OLTP\SQL2014],
  'USE master;
  DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, -10, SYSDATETIME());     
  DECLARE @ToDate   DATETIME = SYSDATETIME();
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
      N''SELECT name 
          FROM sys.tables 
          JOIN sys.partitions
            ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.partitions.object_id 
          WHERE sys.tables.create_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
            AND sys.tables.name LIKE ''''%EXCEPTION%''''
            AND NOT sys.tables.name LIKE ''''%AUDIT''''
            AND sys.partitions.rows <> 0'';

   EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
       @sql
       ,N''@FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME''
       ,@FromDate
       ,@ToDate;
');
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT name
FROM OPENQUERY ( [OLTP\SQL2014],
  'USE master;
  DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME = DATEADD(dd, -10, SYSDATETIME());     
  DECLARE @ToDate   DATETIME = SYSDATETIME();

  EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql]
       N''SELECT name 
          FROM sys.tables 
          JOIN sys.partitions
            ON sys.tables.object_id = sys.partitions.object_id 
          WHERE sys.tables.create_date BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate
            AND sys.tables.name LIKE ''''%EXCEPTION%''''
            AND NOT sys.tables.name LIKE ''''%AUDIT''''
            AND sys.partitions.rows <> 0''
       ,N''@FromDate DATETIME, @ToDate DATETIME''
       ,@FromDate
       ,@ToDate;
');
```

Comment: I like it. When I try to run it, it gives me a couple of errors though. `Must declare the scalar variable "@sql".` and `Incorrect syntax near ' AND sys.partitions.rows <> 0'

Comment: @SeanLong See my updated answer and check if first problem is gone

Comment: It is, but now there's the error `Procedure expects parameter '@params' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'. I'm gonna play with it. I doubt I could CAST datetype as one of those and still do the comparison.

Comment: @SeanLong Updated one more time, try this one

Comment: `%EXCEPTION%` and `%AUDIT` actually need quad-quotes, but it looks good aside from a permissions issue on my end.